# ASP.NET hidden field data lost on postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, postback, hidden-field

I am working on an ASP.NET application (well supposed to be deploying it about 3 days ago) and my hidden fields are loosing value when the form gets posted back..

I am using them to store information i write using javascript and on my own machine this works fine but as soon as i deploy it on our server everything else works except these values are lost..

I am using the .NET AJAX control toolkit on the same page and have noticed my calander datepicker also looses the data..

I have checked using firebug and the data is definitely getting post to the server but is getting lost somewhere!

Comment: well if the value is being sent to the server, what is being lost? what code is attempting to use it and not working?

Comment: well accrding to firebug the post request contains the data im trying to send... on my serverside i have Request.Form["mycontrolidaccordingtofirebug"] and it doesnt work, i have tried adding runat="server" and using mycontrol.Text and it doesnt work any ideas.. it may be something to do with the ASP.NET AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys..

Turns out it was a dumb embarrassing mistake that had nothing to do with the field!

Was a database problem..

I feel Spare!

Sorry!

Thanks!